# Can't type inside a WebView

Tags: android, android-widget, android-webview

I have a problem interacting with a `WebView`. I'm showing an HTML login form within a `WebView` and I can't type inside of any of the input fields of the forms. I do can interact with the links, select boxes, buttons, etc.

Here is an example of my code. Basically I'm retrieving the web view from the xml and setting it a `WebViewClient` and a `WebChromeClient`.

```
webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.loginWebview);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

WebViewClient client = new WebViewClient();
webview.setWebViewClient(client);

webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
webview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10):

You can do the following to solve this:

```
WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.yourWebView);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
```

There is another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083909/android-webview-refusing-user-input).