# Cannot insert text into webview that is on a tab

Tags: android, tabs, android-webview

I have two tabs and each of them contains a webview (with google page, for sake of simplicity). 
The web view loads fine, but when I try to insert some text into Google's search field, the soft keyboard appears as expected, but if I start writing some text, the field loses focus.
It seems that it considers soft keyboard as part of the tab layout and not of the webpage layout.

I've spent hours trying all the solutions I've found, but any of them worked in my case.
For instance: [Why is Android WebView refusing user input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083909/why-is-android-webview-refusing-user-input)  and  [Can't type inside a Web View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653923/cant-type-inside-a-web-view)

Any other idea is really welcome!
I think that all the relevant code is posted below, otherwise just ask.

Thanks!

MainActivity.java (FragmentActivity)

```
public void onTabChanged(String selected) {

Fragment shownFragment = fm.findFragmentByTag(shown);
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

// Remove the current fragment from screen
if (shownFragment != null) {
    ft.remove(shownFragment);
}

// Change to the new fragment
if (selected.equals("Tab1")) {
    shown = "Tab1";
    ft.add(R.id.fragment_content, new WebFragment(), "Tab1");

} else if (selected.equals("Web")) {
    shown = "Web";
    ft.add(R.id.fragment_content, new WebFragment(), "Web");

}

ft.commit();
}
```

WebFragment.java

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {

webView = (WebView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_web_fragment, container, false);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

Log.v("WebFragment", "Returning web view");
webView.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);

return webView;

}

private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    view.loadUrl(url);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideKeyEvent(WebView view, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && view.canGoBack()) {
    view.goBack();
    return true;
    }

    return super.shouldOverrideKeyEvent(view, event);
}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1" 
android:orientation="vertical" 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TabHost android:id="@android:id/tabhost" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <HorizontalScrollView android:id="@+id/hScrollView" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:fillViewport="true" 
            android:scrollbars="none">

            <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:tabStripEnabled="true"/>
        </HorizontalScrollView>

        <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="0dp" 
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0" />

        <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/fragment_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

activity_web_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView android:id="@+id/webView" 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Comment: Do you find out a solution for this problem? I'm facing the exact problem. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Actually, no.. I've used a workaround and I've displayed webview on a single activity without tabs. I think Android was considering the soft keyboard as belonging to the container activity instead of the fragment. Anyway, if you find a solution, please let me know for future needs. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I will. In my case, I need/have to use tabbar.

Answer (score 3):

**Hi Safime,
   I think I found the solution. I'm sure you had searched around and had seen this workaround post over internet as claimed fix the bug:**

```
webview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:                     
                    if (!v.hasFocus()) {
                        v.requestFocus();
                    }
                    break;
            }               
            return false;
        }
    });
```

**However, it didn't work for me then I changed a little and it worked. Hope this help you.**

```
Webview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    //The key is this line. 
                    v.requestFocusFromTouch();  
                    break;
            }               
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: hii i have try but when i use  v.requestFocusFromTouch();   there some scroll issue occur, scroll view not properlly scroll do you plesae help me

Comment: Can you describe the issue you have?