# Android: Can't click into a textbox with WebView

Tags: android, webview

I have what I hope is a simple problem.  I have an application that uses some private JS to display some information.  I'm using WebView to display what's generated by this library.  This particular library generates a text box.  On an emulator I can click into it fine and type some text.  Deployed to an actual Android device yeilds different results.  I can see the text box but I don't seem to be able to click into it.

Is there a setting I need to explicitly set to make sure that the contents of my WebView can be interacted with on an actual device?

Thanks

Comment: Did you enable JavaScript in your Websettings?

Comment: only way we can help you in this case is your source code, post it pls.

Comment: JavaScript is enabled, also tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653923/cant-type-inside-a-web-view.  Will update with source in a sec