# Android: WebView rotation stops keyboard from opening

Tags: android, keyboard, webview

I have a WebView on an activity that the rotation is managed by me (Manifest: `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"`) due to some specific needs.

For testing purposes i'm opening Google.com on it.

The first time, that Google.com opens it all works great. But, after I rotate the device, the focus events seem to stop working.

When pressing the search box of Google.com the soft keyboard doesn't open... there are even no events shown on the LogCat.

Before the rotation these are the logs that appear when pressing google.com search box and the keyboard is opening:

```
08-19 11:13:19.765: INFO/KeyInputQueue(2497): Input event
08-19 11:13:19.765: DEBUG/KeyInputQueue(2497): screenCaptureKeyFlag setting 0
08-19 11:13:19.769: ERROR/KeyLedTest(2581): KeyLedTest++
08-19 11:13:19.773: ERROR/KeyBoardLed(2497): UpdateState../sys/class/sec/keyboard/keyboard_led state false
08-19 11:13:19.773: ERROR/KeyBoardLed(2497): UpdateState../sys/class/sec/keyboard/keyboard_led state false finished
08-19 11:13:19.773: ERROR/KeyLedTest(2581): service.UpdateState0
```

After rotating none is shown when pressing...

I've tried to see if `onConfigurationChanged` method is called, when pressing the search box but it is not. I've also tried to remove the keyboard from Manifest being `android:configChanges="orientation"` but none has taken any effect.

Any clue someone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe your `WebView` is not having focus?

A similar question has been asked: [Why is Android WebView refusing user input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083909/android-webview-refusing-user-input)
and the solution was to add the following line:

`webView.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);`