# Android Keypad not getting displayed

Tags: android, webview

I am developing an Android application.In that i m having one webview and i m loading my server url into that webview like say.

WebView.loadUrl("serverurl");

and it also has 1 refresh button. which on clicked,again webview is getting loaded.but the problem is that after refresh button is clicked,Android keypad is not getting displayed to type anythng after clicking on the textbox of the login page coming from the server.

Not getting how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

this link really helped :
[Why is Android WebView refusing user input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083909/android-webview-refusing-user-input?rq=1)

Just added

webView.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);

and it solved the problem.