# How can I trigger focus on a text input field in a WebView after page load?

Tags: android, android-webview, nexus-player

I'm attempting to load the Facebook sign in page in a `WebView` that is running on the Nexus Player.  This device outputs to a TV and as such does not have a touch screen.

I can get the sign in page to load without issue, but the user is unable to select the email and password text fields in order to enter their credentials.

Pushing up/down/left/right on the Nexus Player remote results in the web page scrolling, but I'm unable to interact with anything on the page itself.

Things I've tried:

- `WebView.requestFocus()` after page loads (from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3975109/758458)
- Simulate a touch input after page loads (from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7001356/758458)
- Hooking up a mouse to the usb port on the Nexus Player.  This worked, and I was able to login successfully, but I can't expect the end-user of my app to do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to execute the following javascript on my `WebView` in `onPageFinished()`:

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByName('email')[0].focus();");
```

Obviously this will only work with the Facebook sign in screen, since they have a text field with name 'email'.

Comment: I know it's an old question, but I have to try: can you still remember/find how you gained a reference to the webView? I am using the Facebook SDK and I am only calling logInWithReadPermissions, I don't get access to the webView they are creating for the login.