# In Android Webview loaded URL in which EditText is not getting focus and keyboard is not launching

Tags: android, android-webview

> Below URL is loaded in webview and EditText feild is not gaining focus
> as a result keyboard is not displayed.
>
> **Loaded URL in WebView :**
> https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeICt0NT0xWZZV1iwLEaaZnnw5n5-8iRGt6HGQHQ9QFq1xpyA/viewform?c=0&w=1
>
> **Tried Solutions :**
> [Why is Android WebView refusing user input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083909/why-is-android-webview-refusing-user-input)

Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: Can show what for code you have? How do you load it?

Comment: Thanks for ur time and i solved the problem by just doing this android:focusableInTouchMode="true"

Comment: Okey no problem only thing you need to do is answer your own question.

Comment: Yes thanks for the info did it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Found the issue :**

```
<WebView
            android:id="@+id/common_webview_id"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"></WebView>
```

> The problem was "focusableInTouchMode" attribute value was set to
>   "false" i.e android:focusableInTouchMode="false" and it should be
>   **"true"** edit text to gain focus.