# [android 12, 13]Display Content to Second Display and do simulate click and inputs on Second Display

Tags: android-virtualdisplay, android-multi-display, android-presentation

> No, sorry. External displays are display-only in standard Android. You can collect input on the primary display (e.g., your phone or tablet) and use that to affect the contents on the external display (e.g., call pageDown() or pageUp() on the WebView), but that's it.

[MediaRouter - Display content to second screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47792213/mediarouter-display-content-to-second-screen/47792771#47792771)

When creating virtual second display and start other activity in this display, can we simulate the click events or input events in that activity of that second display, just like AccessibilityService?

WHAT: I write an android app to create virtual display and start activity in virtual display.

Expected: I want to start activity displayed on virtual display created, and I hope I can get its window and view information like AccessibilityNodeInfo and try to do simulated click events. Assumed that wechat activity was started on Virtual Display, I want to search the chatroom title, go into it, find the editText we send message to, and perform click the send button automatically in the virtual display.